iOS crash when SFMCSdk.identity.setProfileId(_:) is called
We are using MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.10 and SFMCSDK 1.0.5.
We are getting some crashes when SFMCSdk.identity.setProfileId(_:) is executed.

The exception is:
-[(dynamic class) addOperations:waitUntilFinished:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107325030

We are calling SFMCSdk.identity.setProfileId(_:) from inside the completion handler that is called from SFMCSdk.initializeSdk's ConfigBuilder, this:
  SFMCSdk.initializeSdk(
    ConfigBuilder()
      .setPush(
        config: mobilePushConfiguration, 
        onCompletion: completionHandler << HERE
      )
      .build()
    ) 

That may be the problem?
